# How to assign multiple variables when you don't know how many will be input in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, variables

My program, asks the user to input variables on a loop until they enter a number which will move the program onto the next step; which is finding the highest and lowest numbers of the ones entered. How would I save all the input numbers to separate variables so I can compare them for the highest and lowest when I don't know how many the user will input (like they may enter five numbers the first run, and maybe eleven the next time the program is run)?

Comment: You might wanna look up what an `Array` or `List` is

Comment: You don't need to save all the variables when trying to find the highest or the lowest.  Just save the highest and the lowest.  Just do the test as you read in the value.

Answer (score 0):

- initalize highest to some real low value.
- intialize lowest to some real high value.
- read in the value.
- are we done, if so exit and print results
- else
- if higher than high save to high
- else if lower than low save to low.
- continue getting data.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe use an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```